# Excel formula for finding the position of value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have values in fields like this: 33, 54 , 61, 13 , 11

What I want to achieve is this (get the positions of values high -> low) and wirte this values in another seperate field

```
33 -> 5 
37 -> 2
35 -> 3
34 -> 4
45 -> 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RANK` function.

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$5,0)
```

[image]

The 3rd parameter determines the order (1 for Ascending, 0 for Descending).

---

**Addendum**:

If the values you're trying to rank are in non-contiguous cells (see example above), you can use a named range to refer to them. Here's how, with example:

1. Select the cells / numbers you wish to rank.
2. Click the name box & type a name for them. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I chose `scores` for my example.

   [image]
3. Use the name in the formula to rank each number:

   `=RANK(A1,scores,0)`

   where `A1` points to a cell/value whose rank you're trying to find out

--
Note that duplicate values will be given "tied" ranks. Example:

[image]

Comment: What if does field aren't together?

Comment: @fox I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide a screenshot? If you're dealing with non-contiguous cells, you can create a named range.

Comment: See updated post...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RANK() function to find the rank of a cell in respect to the others.  Assuming your column A contains the values, this goes in B1

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$5,0)
```

Copy to each cell in B.

The final "0" denotes descending, ie, your highest value gets rank 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small number of **non-contiguous** cells which contain the values to be ranked, e.g. A11, A13, A33, A54, A61 then you can still use `RANK` function like this

`=RANK(A11,(A$11,A$13,A$33,A$54,A$61))`

a named range will also work as per Kaze's suggestion....

Comment: Doesn't work. Actually I'm doing this in libreCalc. Does it maybe have somekind of different syntax.

Comment: It works OK in Excel - haven't tried libreCalc.....

Comment: They should have upvoted this answer, the question was about excel not libre calc.